# Advertisement popup in footer position

Tags: mobile, ads

I want to know if someone knows how to make a popup advertisemente banner in a mobile site, just like the one you can see in [m.imdb.com](http://m.imdb.com)
It's an ad banner with a close button.
Thanks in advance
Pablo

Answer (score 0):

Solved
This is the script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#freebie").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

And this is the html code

```
<div style="position:fixed; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 999999;" id="freebie">
<a href="http://www.YOUR_URL.com" target="_blank"><img src="YOUR_IMAGE.jpg" border="0" style="background-color:black; opacity:0.85; height:50px; width:100%; position:absolute; bottom: 0px; z-index:-1;"></a>
<a href="javascript:hidefreebie();"><img style="margin-right: 0px;margin-top: -60px;position: absolute;right: 0;top: 0;" src="SOME_CLOSE_BUTTON.png" border="0"></a>
</div>
```

Cheers!